# Server/Systems monitoring with Jabber?

Tags: monitoring, xmpp

I was just thinking about how Jabber and IM systems in general deal in "presence notification". I thought it'd be a neat hack to have a server (or possibly an individual application) log on to a Jabber account.

This does a couple things.

1. You have a convenient way to monitor your servers in near-real time.
2. It opens the possibility to instrumenting your server or app with informational commands that can be accessed through Jabber.

Has anyone seen this implemented?

FYI: Jabber is the protocol behind Google Talk.

Comment: Might want to reference XMPP (the official name of the protocol created by and used with Jabber), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA can notify users when a support issue assigned to them is updated by a client: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Jabber+Notifier+Listener

Zutubi supports jabber integration http://coedify.com/products/pulse/features/tour/continuousintegration/

Nagios can notify you via jabber http://www.nagios.org/faqs/viewfaq.php?faq_id=50

In short - yes it is a very cool idea but AFAIK only a very small number of apps support it right now. There are probably a lot more than I have listed here. Unfortunately jabber I haven't seen that many plaaces using jabber personally, the Microsoft Communicator product seems to be taking over.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Nagzilla](http://code.google.com/p/nagzilla/).

> Nagzilla is a daemon, which allows us
>   to get alerts from various systems and
>   event creators. It sits quietly in a
>   room until it gets a message to relay
>   to either a chatroom or a person.
>   Nagzillac (the client program) accepts
>   any string input and makes it into a
>   Jabber message.

-- http://www.hurricanelabs.com/opensource

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Vertebra](http://www.engineyard.com/vertebra) which is...

> a framework for orchestrating complex processes in a Cloud. It is designed with an emphasis on security, fault tolerance, and portability.